# MongoDB queries between many collections

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. In the application I'm looking at, the documents in a small number of collections (say 5% of the total number) need to reference documents in many other collections (say 50%).

For example, say I have "normal" collections A - N, and "referencing" collections X - Z. A document in collection X needs to be able to reference any document in collections A - N, something like this:

```
{ _id: "X1", coll: "A", doc_id: "A123" }
{ _id: "X2", coll: "B", doc_id: "B456" }
...
{ _id: "X14", coll: "N", doc_id: "N789" }
```

I need to be able to retrieve the documents from collections A - N that these documents point to. What's the best way to do that?

Although MongoDB has [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/), apparently they [break](https://www.compose.com/articles/mongodb-and-the-trouble-with-dbrefs/) if you copy documents between databases, due to random re-ordering of the $ref, $id, and $db fields. Copying between databases is something I often need to do.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you could share your code, the community can perhaps figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @MiB_Coder, thanks for your reply! I have no code at the moment as I'm just evaluating whether MongoDB will be suitable for this application. In the article that I referenced ( https://www.compose.com/articles/mongodb-and-the-trouble-with-dbrefs/ ), the section at the end "Looking up the alternative" suggests that the $lookup operator could be used instead of DBRefs, but he doesn't explain how that would be done.